# Collide with objects in matrix C#

Tags: c#

I'm creating Atari Breakout in C# for school. But I'm stuck on the collision with the blocks on top. The blocks are Labels. The y position of the ball is yBall. The x position of the ball is xBall.

**My question is:** How to let the ball collide with all of the blocks and remove the block the ball collides with?
Here is my code:

LevelGenerator:

```
// Block array
Block[] block = new Block[150];
// Matrix
byte[] pos = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
               4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
               5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
               6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
               7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
               8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 };

// These values are increased with a Timer
int xBall = 500;
int yBall = 800;

public LevelGenerator() {
    createBlocks(pos);
}

private void createBlocks(byte[] posi)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < posi.Length; a++)
        {
            switch (posi[a])
            {
                case 1:
                    block[a] = new Block(posi, a, form);
                    block[a].BackColor = Color.Red;
                    this.Controls.Add(block[a]);
                    block[a].BringToFront();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    block[a] = new Block(posi, a, form);
                    block[a].BackColor = Color.Orange;
                    this.Controls.Add(block[a]);
                    block[a].BringToFront();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    block[a] = new Block(posi, a, form);
                    block[a].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    this.Controls.Add(block[a]);
                    block[a].BringToFront();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    block[a] = new Block(posi, a, form);
                    block[a].BackColor = Color.Lime;
                    this.Controls.Add(block[a]);
                    block[a].BringToFront();
                    break;

                case 5:
                    block[a] = new Block(posi, a, form);
                    block[a].BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                    this.Controls.Add(block[a]);
                    block[a].BringToFront();
                    break;

                case 6:
                    block[a] = new Block(posi, a, form);
                    block[a].BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    this.Controls.Add(block[a]);
                    block[a].BringToFront();
                    break;

                case 7:
                    block[a] = new Block(posi, a, form);
                    block[a].BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
                    this.Controls.Add(block[a]);
                    block[a].BringToFront();
                    break;

                case 8:
                    block[a] = new Block(posi, a, form);
                    block[a].BackColor = Color.Purple;
                    this.Controls.Add(block[a]);
                    block[a].BringToFront();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What doesn't work with trying to get them to collide? If you don't have any ideas on how to start, we can't help you.

Comment: Take a look at `System.Windows.Rect` you can create a simple rectangles. You can make one from your bal position and then use the `IntersectsWith()` method to test vs all blocks rectangles. If it intersect then you know which block it collided with.

Comment: If i may suggest code cleanup, you should change your `byte[]` to a `Color[]` your loop wont have a switch case anymore the whole method will shrink from 63 lines to 10

Comment: Might I suggest using the `Unity3d` engine? If you're allowed to, you could knock something like this together in a couple of hours.